# How to check input against a huge list?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
while True:  
    print(vehiclelist)  
     reg = input('Enter registration number of vehicle: ')  
     if reg in vehiclelist:  
         break  
     else:  
         print("Invalid")
```

But it keeps showing its invalid, this is the output:

> [Car('SJV1883R', 'Honda', 'Civic', 60.00), Car('SJZ2987A', 'Toyota', 'Altis', 60.00), Car('SKA4370H', 'Honda', 'Accord', 80.00),
>   Car('SKD8024M', 'Toyota', 'Camry', 80.00), Car('SKH5922D', 'BMW',
>   '320i', 90.00), Car('SKM5139C', 'BMW', '520i', 100.00),
>   Car('SKP8899H', 'Mercedes', 'S500', 300.00), Truck('GB3221K', 'Tata',
>   'Magic', 200.00), Truck('YB8283M', 'Isuzu', 'NPR', 250.00),
>   Truck('YK5133H', 'Isuzu', 'NQR', 300.00)]
>       Enter registration number of vehicle: SJZ2987A
>       Invalid

Any idea how I can check the input?

This is my vehicle class:

```
class Vehicle():
    def __init__(self, regNo, make, model, dailyRate, available):
        self.regNo = regNo
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.dailyRate = dailyRate
        self.available = available

    @property
    def dailyRate(self):
        return self.__dailyRate

    @dailyRate.setter
    def dailyRate(self, dailyRate):
        if dailyRate < 0:
            self.__dailyRate = 0
        else:
            self.__dailyRate = dailyRate

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Vehicle('{:s}', '{:s}', '{:s}', {:.2f}, '{:s}')".format(self.regNo, self.make, self.model, self.dailyRate, self.available)
```

Comment: It is not in vehicle list. That list contains vehicle objects (I assume). You need to access their registration number attributes and search in that list. Of course you'll need to show your vehicle class to get help on that.

Comment: `vehiclelist` contains `Car`s, which are not registration numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here the problem is `vehicle_list` is a list of Vehicle objects and you can not directly search for a registration number inside a list of vehicle object.

A better design pattern is to use a dictionary in which `regNo` will appear as key and vehicle object will appear as value.

You may change your code as follows:

```
vehicle_details = {vehicle.regNo : vehicle for vehicle in vehiclelist}
while True:  
    reg = input('Enter registration number of vehicle: ')  
    if reg in vehicle_details:  
        break  
    else:  
        print("Invalid")
```

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for suggestion. I have edited my code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the individual car objects and compare the `regNo`

```
def getInput():
    while True:
        print(vehiclelist)  
        reg = input('Enter registration number of vehicle: ')
        for car in vehiclelist:
            if reg == car.regNo:
                return
        print("Invalid")
```